# Does $a =\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$ implies that $a =\sum_{i = 1}^\infty x_i$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm wondering about the following statement: Let's say that for any $n \in \mathbb N$:

$$ \exists_{x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in \mathbb R} : a = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$$

Can I also say that there exists $x_1,x_2,... \in \mathbb R$ such that:

$$a = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty x_i$$

? In my intuition is that we have equality of $a =  \sum_{i = 1}^nx_i$ and we can take limit of both sides, but $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a = a$. Could you please tell me if my intuition is correct?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that you can take limit on both sides, because the right hand side is only defined for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. You can just take $x_i = 0$ for all $i>n$.